# Выражение "аля", как правильно его выделять?

Tags: пунктуация

Я часто встречаю выражение "аля" и часто вижу различную пунктуацию. В интернете я никакого конкретного пояснения не нашла, как оно должно обособляться, если должно. Зато вариантов море: с кавычками, без кавычек, с тире или вообще без знаков препинания - на любой вкус. Вот несколько примеров:

– Я участвую! – с улыбкой "аля я всех сделаю" сказала девушка. (?)

С выражением на лице: аля "вам не повезло".

С глазами, аля "я милашка".

Это, конечно, далеко не всё, вариаций много, но объясните, пожалуйста, как же всё-таки правильно?

Извиняюсь, что "а-ля" без дефиса, но просто пишу, как видела.

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически, предлог А-ЛЯ должен писаться раздельно, так как происходит от французского "à la", то есть "наподобие", "подобно", "словно", и графически должен передаваться идентично. Однако в русском языке уже существует отдельная лексико-грамматическая единица - противительный союз А. И чтобы не было путаницы, предлог принято писать через дефис, то есть две независимые языковых единицы объединены единым смыслом. По сути, это лексическая калька. Без дефиса сочетание "а ля" может встречаться в предложении: "Скрипач сыграл не ноту ми, а ля".

Comment: Думаю, что мотив написания через дефис проще. В русском не используются составные предлоги с раздельным написанием (мы пишем: из-за, из-под), если же транскрипции подвергается не предлог, а идентичное в написании сочетание предлога с артиклем, то оснований для объединения дефисом нет: "а ла гер ком а ла гер".

Comment: Когда я впервые столкнулась с этим, то нашла ответ на Грамоте ру, там утверждают, что через дефис.

Comment: Да, многие именитые авторы пишут, что сочетание пишеися именно через дефис, однако, чисто логически, раздельное написание "а ля" не выглядит как грамматическая ошибка, хотя бы потому, что сопоставляется с оригиналом, по аналогии "а ля гер ком а ля гер". Скажем, фраза "Асталависта" выглядят как допустимая графическая форма идиомы "Аста ла виста", хотя во втором случае раздельное написание будет считаться достоверной грамматической калькой.

Answer (score 1):

[а-ля](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D1%8F) (от франц. à la):

> Он любил вставать в позу а-ля Наполеон.

<sup>Т. е. запятыми оно не выделяется ни до, ни после.</sup>

Я бы писал так:

> – Я участвую! – с улыбкой а-ля «я всех сделаю» сказала девушка.
>   С выражением на лице а-ля «вам не повезло».
>   С глазами а-ля «я милашка».

**Upd.:**

Да, `а-ля` может писаться и раздельно (`а ля`).